# Leverage 50 AMP Hot Tub power source for EV Charging

Tags: car, ev-charging

**Question:** Can I repurpose 50amp wiring intended for a hot tub to be used to install a 14/50 Nema outlet in the garage to charge my Electric car?

**Background:** I am planning on having a new 50 amp breaker installed in my breaker box, 35ft of Romex conduit run to the garage, and a 14/50 outlet. I know this is going to be somewhat pricey (waiting on estimates from the electrician). When looking at the breaker box today for something else, I noticed a 50amp breaker labeled "Hot Tub Disconnect". It made me wonder if maybe there is an existing power source I can leverage. I moved into this home 2 years ago and it does not have a hot tub.

Lo and behold, on the outer wall of my garage I found these two boxes a foot from each other. One looks to be a hot tub disconnect and the other has some power wires with wire nuts. Pictures below.

Assuming these wires are the 50amp power for the hot tub, can I just instead have it routed through the wall to the garage and have the outlet installed there?[image]

Comment: If no hot tub, then quite possible.  Depending on the age of the circuit, quite possible there already is GFCI protection required for garage receptacles.  GFCI is required for receptacles/plug ins, but is expensive, why hard wiring EV chargers is recommended.  50 amp EV chargers is like corvettes for car owners, very nice for the ego, but not needed most times.  The wires will be okay to use even if you went with 30 amp charger.

Comment: Can you confirm wire size? It doesn't look like anything bigger than @0 or 30A wire.

Comment: I think it is Romex 6 from the electric panel to the outdoor box. In the outdoor box, what should I be seeing to verify those wires can handle the amperage? I have two electric panels and the panel with the Hot tub wiring has (3) 30 amp breakers with orange Romex (R) connected to these. Then I have (4) 40 amp Romex black cables. This electric panel only has one 50 amp (the Hot tub) and it also has a black Romex connected, but I could not find any writing the black cables. The cable to the 50 amp breakers is thicker than the other four Romex cables.

Comment: My other electric panel has multiple 50amp breakers and uses the same thickness wire that is labeled Hot tub. The electrician noted I have good panels and that the existing 50 amp breakers used Romex 6. Unfortunately, I did not ask him about using the Hot tub breaker when he was here as I had not noticed it. Regarding the age of the circuit, the house was built in 2010. The electric panel is an ETN CSH 35K

Comment: ETN CSH 35K is a spec of the main breaker. Which tells us that it is an Eaton panel but not much else.

Answer (score 2):

##### TL;DR Yes, But Don't Do It

Yes, you can reuse the 50A feed for EV charging. You need to make sure the wires are appropriate size (6 AWG or larger if NM cable (a.k.a., Romex), 8 AWG or larger if individual wires), though if it turns out they were undersized you can use them (with a breaker change) for whatever ampacity they can handle. See an [ampacity chart](https://www.cerrowire.com/products/resources/tables-calculators/ampacity-charts/) for details.

But don't install a 14-50. That is the wrong way to do things. Now that Stellantis is on board, all the major car manufacturers in the US are moving to NACS over the next 2 years, and providing adapters until then. So get an NACS charger (the Tesla charger is great, but others are perfectly fine as well) and **hardwire** it. That gives you a few advantages:

- One less piece of equipment. In particular, there are many reports of basic 14-50 receptacles (which may be fine for an oven, for example) not working reliably long-term for EV charging. This saves that cost.
- If your jurisdiction is currently on a version of the NEC that requires GFCI on 240V receptacles (many are, many are not, some have made specific exceptions to this rule, varies by jurisdiction), hardwiring avoids (legitimately) the requirement, saving additional money and avoiding certain types of problems.
- Unless you are planning to use the same receptacle for welding or some other high-power device, you're just going to leave the EV charger/cable plugged in to the receptacle all the time anyway, so you don't lose anything by hardwiring.

Comment: Is it the plugging/unplugging the issue for receptacles?

Comment: Multiple issues: typical 50A receptacles are not designed for frequent plugging/unplugging - you need the kind used at RV parks (same 14-50 but better quality) to handle that. But also the cheaper ones tend to not handle 40A continuous very well, and EVs do that where typical RV usage and welding and so on do not. Plus the GFCI issue.

Comment: Reusing hot tub wiring is exactly how I did my first EVSE install at my previous house. Were I to do it again, I'd do everything the same, except for skipping the 14-50 and hardwiring. This answer is spot on.

Comment: I was mainly going with a receptacle instead of hard wiring since I already have a Tesla mobile wireless charger that allows me to pop off the current 120v plug (5-15 Nema) and replace it with a Tesla-branded 14/50 Nema plug. This charger would protect the car if something shorted out and would stay plugged into the receptacle full time. However, if the receptacle is dangerous, will totally go the hardwire route. The electrician mentioned using an RV type receptable.

Comment: The benefit of hardwiring is it offers faster charing in addition to what sounds like a safer setup. So I think I may go that route. I was cheapening out a bit trying to save the $450 cost for the Tesla Wall Connecter.

Comment: Hardwiring does not *inherently* mean faster charging. Charging at (way more than really needed) 40A continuous, 50A breaker/circuit is **exactly the same** whether plugged in to a 14-50 or hardwired. (Or 32A/40A or 16A/20A, etc.) It is *possible* to hardwire at even higher rates than 40A/50A, but normal residential usage has no need for that, and also doing that often requires an increase in the utility service, which gets expensive. But consider that if you use a "travel charger" that isn't free, plus add GFCI plus add the receptacle and you're a good chunk of the way to $450.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact No, it is absolutely **not** "exactly the same". Hardwiring *actually* is faster. Plug-in EVSEs with a 14-50 plug will only draw 32A, because 14-50 receptacles are legal to install on 40A circuits. Hard-wiring is the only way to actually charge at 40A on a 50A circuit.

Comment: Practically speaking it doesn't make much difference to average drivers (50 miles can be replenished overnight for most EVs even on a 15A 240V circuit no problem), but there is a difference.

Comment: @nobody the travel charger that came with the 2023 BMW i4 _will_ draw 9600W from a 14-50 receptacle if you tell it to. I usually set it to run somewhere between 12A and 32A though, since like you said, I’m gonna be fully charged in the morning either way.

Comment: @JacobKrall But it looks like nobody is correct at least with respect to the Tesla Mobile Connector based on the manual - it treats a 14-50 as a 40A circuit, 32A rate of charge.

Comment: I did not realize that the Tesla mobile charger maxed out at 32 amps where as the Tesla wall connector is 48. On that note, can a 50 amp breaker feed a 48 amp device? I thought I needed a 10% buffer, which would mean I need a 60 amp breaker.

Comment: The "buffer" is 20% or 25% depending on your perspective. You can look at it as: Add 25% to the actual load to get the circuit size (and therefore the wire size). Or as: Start with circuit size (and wire size) and subtract 20% to get to the allowable continuous usage. So either 48A x 1.25 = 60A, or 60A x 0.8 = 48A. Bottom line: 60A circuit = 48A charge rate, 50A circuit = 40A charge rate, 40A circuit = 32A charge rate, 30A circuit = 24A charge rate, 20A circuit = 16A charge rate. Believe it or not, 20A (16A) or 30A (24A) is actually enough for the typical user (excluding people with super-long

Comment: commutes or Uber/Lyft drivers). If your typical mileage per day is 100 or less (which is the case for the vast majority of Americans) then consider that that [based on Tesla's info](https://www.tesla.com/support/charging/wall-connector#vehicle-charging-speeds) a 20A circuit will add 12 to 15 miles of range per hour of charging. Which means 8 hours while you sleep will get you on the order of 100 miles of range. Most people have a longer typical charge time than that (start charging earlier in the evening), 30A will bump it another 50%,

Comment: some models (according to the Tesla page, model 3 & Y rear-drive) can't take more than 32A (40A circuit) AC anyway, and in the other direction cold weather, towing or other factors can increase the power required per mile of actual range. But TL;DR 30A (24A rate) circuit is almost certainly enough 40A (32A rate) is far more than enough and 50A (40A rate) may actually be more than your car can even use. 60A (48A) - way overkill unless you have 3 EVs (3 EVSE with shared pool, each one actually would get less than 60/48).